# String replace within SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to replace all occurrences of `?` with a single empty space within a table for all columns.

Example:

```
This is a?string
```

would become

```
This is a string
```

Currently I have found out how to do it for one column only

```
UPDATE tableName
   SET columnName = REPLACE(columnName,'"','\'')
```

Is there a way to select and apply to al columns? I don't wish to 'try' it as if the table becomes corrupted or deleted it will cause a lot of upset. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in ur update statement you need to specify all the columns where you need the replacement  like : `UPDATE tableName
   SET column1 = REPLACE(column1,'"','\''),column2 = REPLACE(column2,'"','\'') ... `

Comment: Make a **backup** before you do anything. And nobody will be upset...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they helped a lot. At least i know that there is no way of using `*` to `UPDATE` all columns. Hopefully this question helps others out also.

Comment: @ppeterka66 thanks for the advice, by exporting it as a CSV?

Comment: @StevenPHP CSV would not be bad, but for example using PHPMyAdmin, you can get SQL INSERT statements, which are a lot easier to restore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try before you buy:

```
SELECT Replace(columnName1, '?', ' ')
     , Replace(columnName2, '?', ' ')
     , Replace(columnName3, '?', ' ')
FROM   your_table
```

Then update if you're happy with the results

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    columnName1 = Replace(columnName1, '?', ' ')
     , columnName2 = Replace(columnName2, '?', ' ')
     , columnName3 = Replace(columnName3, '?', ' ')
```

---

### Update

You may wish to limit the effect of your query. At current it will apply to every row in your table, regardless of whether any question marks exist in the column values or not.

Therefore you should consider adding a `WHERE` clause that checks for the existence.

```
SELECT Replace(columnName1, '?', ' ')
FROM   your_table
WHERE  Locate('?', columnName1) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it for all columns automatically, you'll need to list the columns individually, but you can still do it with one statement:

```
UPDATE tableName
   SET columnName1 = REPLACE(columnName1,'"','\''),
       columnName2 = REPLACE(columnName2,'"','\''),
       columnName3 = REPLACE(columnName3,'"','\''),
       ...
       columnNameN = REPLACE(columnNameN,'"','\'')
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Would my `?` character go where the `"` is or the `\` is, in your example?

Comment: @StevenPHP If you're replacing `?` with ` `, then your `REPLACE` line would be `columnNameX = REPLACE(columnNameX, '?', ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shortcut to create an update statement for all the fields in a table.  You would fill in the table name and database name in the `WHERE` clause of the SQL statements below, then run the code and it will return a SQL statement that you could copy and then run.

For a separate update statement for each field in a table:

```
SELECT concat('UPDATE ', TABLE_NAME, ' SET ', COLUMN_NAME, ' = REPLACE(', COLUMN_NAME, ', ''?'', '''')')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name';
```

For a single update statement for every field in a table.  Put `UPDATE table_name` then paste the results of this SQL statement.

```
SELECT concat('SET ', COLUMN_NAME, ' = REPLACE(', COLUMN_NAME, ', ''?'', ''''),')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name';
```

If you just wanted to do update char or varchar fields you could add this to your `WHERE` clause:

```
 AND DATA_TYPE in ('char', 'varchar')
```

To do it for every table in a database, simply drop the TABLE_NAME logic from your `WHERE` clause.